# How to pass values from JS to HTML tags in lightning web component?

Tags: javascript, html, web, salesforce, lwc

I am trying to pass color to the existing style of HTML tag from Javascript. However, it's not working as I am trying. Please help.

Actual HTML

```
<template if:true={bmirange1}>
    <div style="color: red; position:auto">BMI: {bmiValue}</div>
</template>
```

What I am trying

```
<template if:true={bmirange1}>
    <div style="color:"{colorcode}"; position:auto">BMI: {bmiValue}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: How about escaping the quotes? Like `"color:\"{colorcode}\";..."`

Comment: Tried but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate values in the tempate, but if `colorcode` has `red` as default value, you could define a getter that returns the whole content of style attribute:
**JS**

```js
get divStyle() {
    return `position:auto; color ${this.colorcode}`;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<template if:true={bmirange1}>
    <div style={divStyle}>BMI: {bmiValue}</div>
</template>
```

---

You could also define an appropriate class for that color in the CSS file and set the color via a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (i.e. `--bmi-color`):

```css
.dynamicColor {
     color: var(--bmi-color, red);
}
```

In the JS, when the `colorcode` property changes, you will have to set this css custom property too:

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bmi-color', this.colorcode);
```

Then your template would be

```html
<template if:true={bmirange1}>
    <div class="dynamicColor" style="position:auto">BMI: {bmiValue}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Awesome. I had some idea that concatenation is not possible in such scenarios & so we can use JS to get the entire style value. But was unware of custom properties in CSS. It worked. Thank you so much!!